# Install latest Gwibber (friends-app) in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gwibber, friends-app

Twitter is broken in the version of Gwibber that comes with 12.04 (version 3.4.X).

Is there a way to install friends-app?

I followed these steps but the PPA doesn't have a version for Ubuntu Precise.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-friends-app-gwibber-rewritten.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

no. It is currently not possible to install the Friends app in 12.04.

### Long answer:

Gwibber has been rewritten in QML/Qt5 and some of the required packages are not available for 12.04. So could I just manually download and install the required packages? you ask. Theoretically you *could*, and I tried it, but after upgrading a package for a dependency of a dependency of a dependency and breaking a few system wide dependencies in the process I gave up.

So, *theoretically*: yes, you could upgrade and install the needed packages.

In reality, no. By the time you figure out all the dependency issues you will get you will pretty much have manually upgraded your Precise system into a Raring one and most likely broken it in the process.

Comment: ouch... So I guess the real question is "Whats a good friends-app alternative for Ubuntu 12.04"?

Comment: @Uriel I would ask a new question about that. Be sure to link me up when you do :)