# Twitter client replacement in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise?

Tags: software-recommendation, gwibber, twitter

Gwibber in 12.04 no longer works with Twitter. (I believe because the API changed).
It appears that its replacement, friends-app, cannot be installed in Precise 
(as per [Install latest Gwibber (friends-app) in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322795/install-latest-gwibber-friends-app-in-ubuntu-12-04)).

So what's a replacement/workaround for a Twitter client in Ubuntu 12.04?
I've tried Hotot and it's also broken for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the twitter client **[polly](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/tools/twitter-polly-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-12-10)**.

Open the terminal and execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-unstable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install polly
```

After that you can start polly from the dash like any other application.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Birdie**, which is the default for elementary OS.

You can install it from ppa by running below commands one by one (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:birdie-team/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install birdie
```

Homepage: http://birdieapp.github.io/

Comment: Even though this is the stable PPA, birdie will constantly crash on me...

Comment: Me too. Always crash when starting.