# Gwibber brings me to System Settings

Tags: 12.04, gwibber, system-settings

So today I decided to install gwibber but, when I try to add accounts it brings me to here:
[image: What do I DO?]

EDIT:Woops What do I do?

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: By the repositorys like it said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing from Ubuntu Apps, just click [**Gwibber** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gwibber/).

Comment: Thats what I did also

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322795/install-latest-gwibber-friends-app-in-ubuntu-12-04).