# Unable to locate package friends-app

Tags: apt

Would appreciate the help

```
$ sudo apt-get install friends-app  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package friends-app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `friends-app` is only avail able for Ubuntu 13.04 onwards. You can search [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for it.

There is some ppa to install it on Ubuntu 12.10 See [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-friends-app-gwibber-rewritten.html)

And if you are using Ubuntu 12.04 you can not have this. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322795/install-latest-gwibber-friends-app-in-ubuntu-12-04)